# In Power BI drill thru target page, how to show all values in a slicer that uses same field as the drill thru dimension?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a SUMMARY page showing aggregate fact information by a given dimension.  I have a DETAILS drill through page configured using that same dimension.

[image: relationships]
[image: summary table drill thru]
[image: drill thru parameter]
[image: current behavior]

How can I allow a drill through operation to occur on a specific dimension while also providing a slicer for that same dimension on the target page that allows the user to switch dimensions?

[image: desired behavior]

Objectives

1. Have a slicer on the details page showing all possible dimensional values
2. Set the slicer value to the value passed by the drill thru action without filtering the slicers other values
3. Allow the user to change the dimension details shown using the slicer... effectively changing the original drillthru selection

See [linked sample file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kYN8tlUyoilgmJ3_7gl6iR5rFaU-D8qE/view?usp=drivesdk) and screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this functionality is not possible out of the box, but could perhaps be emulated using a bookmark - I have no way of trying this out for the moment, but I envision the following steps:

- Be in the drillthrough page
- Make sure there are no active filters on the dimension you want to lift the filter on
- Create a new bookmark, make sure the bookmark stores the filter / data context
- Add a button to the page, and assign this bookmark as an action

You can also simply duplicate the drill through page and allow the user to navigate to the unfiltered "sister" page from the drillthrough page. Add a button to return to the original page to both pages to ensure you can "loop back".